# Calculating elasticities using a mixed effects model with lmer package in R

Tags: r, mixed-models, elasticity

I have data for ten grocery stores, with weekly sales for multiple products (about 1000) during 3 years.

I'm trying to calculate store level elasticity to compare between those ten stores. Let's assume that all I have as variables are `store_id`, `product_id`, `unit sales`, `price` and `week number`.

The regression that I'm trying to fit is the following (looping for each store individually):

```
log(units) ~ log(price) + month + (1+log(price)|product_id)
```

I'm assuming I get elasticity coefficient for each store in the fixed effect and random effects are the elasticity variation by product in each store. First, am I correct with my assumption here?

If price and unit volume vary significantly by product, for example:

> Product A sells on average 1000 units per week at a price $5.99
>
> Product B sells on average 100 units per week with price $15.50

Do I need to scale both units and price by product so that a given product does not have an outsized impact on overall elasticity (the fixed effect)?

If this is not the ideal model to run, would you recommend a better approach?